# Чистый JS: передать объект через POST-запрос для PHP

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Требуется силами ванильного JS передать на PHP сервер через POST-запрос объект так, чтобы PHP сам его распознал и разместил в массиве $_POST.

Если я хочу передать в теле простой объект вида: `{name1: 'value1', name2: 'value2'}`
то мне достаточно будет преобразовать его к строке: `'name1=value1&name2=value2'`
и умный PHP всё сделает сам.

А если мне необходимо передать составной объект следующего вида:

```
{
  name1:{
    name1sub1: 'value1sub1',
    name1sub2: 'value1sub2',
  },
  name2:{
    name2sub1: 'value2sub1',
    name2sub2: 'value2sub2',
  }
}
```

то каким образом это запаковать в строку такого же формата, как и в первом случае, чтобы к объекту можно было обратиться через $_POST?

По-любому способ должен быть, ведь JQ это как-то делает :-)

Да, я понимаю, что любую необработанную информацию можно получить через `file_get_contents('php://input')`, но мне необходимо правильно всё передать на стороне клиента.

Comment: В инструментах разработчика посмотрите, какой HTTP-запрос отправляет JQ, да повторите то же самое

Comment: `Content-Type` какой отправляете?) `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` или `multipart/form-data`

Comment: [Вот хранилище тут файлы POST формы но там немного специфична она надеюсь пригодиться вам.](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1G16HmbZ1dC-KFQux8P1ELgQbCRjChHb0?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну во-первых я думаю что объект будет лучше отправлять в формате json(если не известно что это то внизу будет ссылка)
А что касается отправки данных на сервер, то стоит воспользоваться Ajax
Вот код а объяснение ниже

```
var body = "jsonstr=" + 
encodeURIComponent(jsonstr);
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "file.php", true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 
'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xhr.send(body);
```

`body` это сам наш запрос который мы посылаем на сервер
`xhr` это объект с помощью которого мы будем отправлять данные на сервер
`xhr.open` это метод который открывает соединение с сервером. Первый параметр это метод отправки, второй php файл к которому идёт запрос, третий это асинхронное выполнение кода (если `false` то синхронное) 
Следующая строка присваивает кодировку запроса
`xhr.send` отправляет запрос
Надеюсь всё более менее понятно
Ссылки:
Здесь целый раздел посвящённый ajax: https://learn.javascript.ru/ajax
Навсякий случай подробнее про json:  https://learn.javascript.ru/json

Comment: Супер! Есть два ключевых момента, на которые потомкам рекомендую обратить внимание.
1. Строка с json начинается с названия параметра и знака равно: "jsonstr=" - это позволяет на стороне сервера обратиться к массиву по данному ключу, чтобы выловить строку перед декодированием: `$obj = json_decode($_POST['jsonstr'])`.
2. Элемент строки json справа от "jsonstr=" обязательно прогонять через encodeURIComponent(), чтобы случайный амперсанд в строке-значении объекта не разрушил весь json. То есть сначала `var jsonstr = JSON.stringify(jsonobj)`, а потом `var body = encodeURIComponent(jsonstr)`.

Comment: Костыли-костылики

Answer (score 1):

> то каким образом это запаковать в строку такого же формата, как и в первом случае, чтобы к объекту можно было обратиться через $_POST?

Использовать [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

Вот так:

```js
var j = {
  name1: {
    name1sub1: 'value1sub1',
    name1sub2: 'value1sub2',
  },
  name2: {
    name2sub1: 'value2sub1',
    name2sub2: 'value2sub2',
  }
};
// Замените на ваш URL
var url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';

fetch(url, {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
      "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(j) // Упаковка

  }).then(response => response.json()) // Ответ с сервера переводится в JSON
  .then(res => console.log(res))
  .catch(function(err) {
    // Error :(
  });
```

Comment: Хороший ответ, работает, но мне нужен был код чуть ниже уровнем. Я бы плюсанул, если бы репутация позволяла... Но более точный и обширный ответ дал Eliot - за счет этого ответа можно понять, как оно там за ширмой вообще работать должно :-)

Comment: @Lex  чтобы понимать как что работает, за ширмой читают, документацию  как минимум.

Answer (score -1):

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var data = {
  name1:{
    name1sub1: 'value1sub1',
    name1sub2: 'value1sub2',
  },
  name2:{
    name2sub1: 'value2sub1',
    name2sub2: 'value2sub2',
  }
};
xhr.open('POST', '/yourUrl');
xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Подробнее о XMLHttpRequest [тут](https://learn.javascript.ru/ajax-xmlhttprequest),
о JSON [тут](https://learn.javascript.ru/json)
Главное - не забудьте разобрать ответ как json на стороне сервера, например вот [так](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php):)